# Delimiter error again

Tags: equations, amsmath, delimiters

How can I fix my delimiter error?

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\ln⁡\Gamma(z)=\ln\biggl[\frac{1}{z} e^{-
z\gamma}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\biggl[\frac{1}{(1+z/n)} e^{z/n}\biggr]\biggr]
&=-\ln⁡z+\ln e^{-z\gamma}+\ln\biggl⁡[\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\biggl[\frac{1}
{(1+z/n)} e^{z/n}\biggr]\biggr]\\
&=-\ln⁡z-z\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln⁡\biggl[\frac{1}{(1+z/n)}
e^{z/n}\biggr] \\
&=-\ln⁡z-z\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\biggl[-\ln⁡\biggl(1+\frac{z}
{n}\biggr)+\frac{z}{n}\biggl]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: please fix your example so people can run it and see the error (as you have not said what the error is)

Comment: Isn't the problem just that you wrote `\lnz` but meant `\ln z`?

Comment: @daleif Surprisingly this is not the (obvious) cause of the error. There is an invisible character between `\ln` and `z` (the code highlighting of the site shows this :).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The character is "U+2061 FUNCTION APPLICATION".  There is an instance, where the character is between `\biggl` and its delimiter `[`, causing the error.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes, that's the one. I posted an answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I don't think the app shows any of that

Comment: @daleif Oh, I assumed the computer version :P https://i.stack.imgur.com/H07F1.png

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I hardly ever use a pc at home, only my tablet. Thanks for the image. I can see the black z in lnz, but can we see the others from the image?

Comment: @daleif No, the others are *more* invisible :P There are 4 more.

Comment: @daleif - I posted an answer with a screenshot that shows all 7 instances of the "hidden" character. To get the output, it's necessary to run the OP's code through LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Mico thanks, today I remember to try to copy the code to emacs, it shows nothing. I wonder if there is a mode that shows zero width chars or what ever this thing is.

Comment: @daleif - I’m afraid I don’t use emacs and thus don’t have any useful suggestions to make. FWIW, the special characters aren’t visible in TeXworks; they do “show up” when run thru LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll call this an unfortunate case of copy-pasting from a dubious source. You had a few hidden characters in the middle of your code. Noticeably, after a `\biggl`, which was the one generating the error.

After a `\biggl` TeX expects a delimiter, but instead it found your mysterious character, thus the error.

Here's a cleaned-up version:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\ln\Gamma(z)=\ln\biggl[\frac{1}{z} e^{-
z\gamma}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\biggl[\frac{1}{(1+z/n)} e^{z/n}\biggr]\biggr]
&=-\ln z+\ln e^{-z\gamma}+\ln\biggl[\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\biggl[\frac{1}
{(1+z/n)} e^{z/n}\biggr]\biggr]\\
&=-\ln z-z\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\biggl[\frac{1}{(1+z/n)}
e^{z/n}\biggr]\\
&=-\ln z-z\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\biggl[-\ln\biggl(1+\frac{z}
{n}\biggr)+\frac{z}{n}\biggl]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

And next time, *please* post a compilable code. It may not be so easy to solve without the bits between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 12):

It's instructive to run your code through a unicode-aware TeX engine, such as LuaLaTeX, while loading the `unicode-math` package. One gets the following screenshot:

[image]

I've highlighted with a yellow marker the seven [7!] instances of an invisible character, U+2061, "function application". (Oddly, there are 9 instances of `\ln`, but "only" 7 of them are followed by the invisible character.) Unsurprisingly, pdfLaTeX chokes on this stuff. Admittedly, the error message about a "missing delimiter" doesn't immediately point you in the right direction.

You may want to check your editor settings and look into the possibility that it's set up to insert the U+2061 character automatically after `\ln`. If that's the case, do suppress that setting.

Replacing all 7 instances of this special character with whitespace, and applying a bit more clean-up to your code, especially to the bracket sizes, produces the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' env.
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\ln \Gamma(z)
&=\ln\biggl[\frac{1}{z} e^{-z\gamma}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}
  \Bigl[\frac{1}{1+z/n} e^{z/n}\Bigr] \biggr]\\
&=-\ln z+\ln e^{-z\gamma}+\ln\biggl[\,\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}
  \Bigl[\frac{1}{1+z/n} e^{z/n}\Bigr]\biggr]\\
&=-\ln z-z\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
  \ln \Bigl[\frac{1}{1+z/n} e^{z/n}\Bigr] \\
&=-\ln z-z\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[-\ln(1+z/n)+z/n] 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Here's a link to the description of the dubious character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2061/index.htm (`contiguity operator indicating application of a function`)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Thanks for this link. I suppose there's a use for this character, *somewhere* -- but not really inside a LaTeX document...